# List obsolete classes/methods in msbuild

Tags: vb.net, msbuild

I have upgraded a visual basic 2005 project to visual basic 2010 (.net framework 4.0). I want to list all obsolete functions used in this project in order to change it with newer ones.

How can I treat obsolete functions warnings as errors in visual basic 2010 ms-build?

Answer (score 0):

User the [**Warnings As Errors**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xz9dxe5.aspx) switch of the vbc (Visual Basic compiler). You can use it via the [Vbc task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb7a1e29.aspx) in MSBuild or set it globally via the `TreatWarningsAsErrors` parameter in your script.